# Robocopy: how do I see what files failed?

Tags: robocopy

I was using robocopy to restore some backed up data after a hard drive failure.
When it finished, it gave a list for some stats, and said that 11 files failed.
How do I find out what files failed?
I can run it again but each time I get the same result.  I always have 11 files failed.

Comment: Welcome. Your question is off topic here. Please read the help section to see what is on-topic. I would advise you to delete this and ask it again on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), where it would be on-topic. We only deal with coding here. Good luck

Comment: Here you can find your answer,
https://superuser.com/questions/992940/robocopy-log-names-of-skipped-failed-files

Comment: Show us your robocopy command. By default, robocopy displays each failed file. So you probably used switches to suppress some logging.